# tcp socket data send in xml packet

Tags: c#, c++, xml, sockets

I'm trying to send some data over tcp socket. Now the thing is instead of sending simple char* data I need to buffer some data and make one xml packet structure out there and therefore send that xml data over the network. For example I have one ini file to read all the data into corresponding variables. say:

```
[Device data ini]

DeviceID = 0042
Manufacturer = Company Name
VendorID = 00-291-647
Timestamp = 2014-08-13 12:40:11
```

Now I need to make the xml out of above data like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataBlock xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <DeviceID>0042</Device>
    <Manufacturer>Company Name</Manufacturer>
    <VendorID>00-291-647</VendorID>
    <TimeStamp>2014-08-13 12:40:11</TimeStamp>
</DataBlock>
```

And send these whole data as char* to server. What would be the best approach to build the xml data packet from simple char* data structure. Code will be written in c++ and the xml will be parsed at the server side with c# code. Any suggestions or recommendation would be off great help.

Comment: What OS/platform for the client?

Comment: Just use a regular xml library like xerces. Google xml parsing c++. For small files DOM is good if the files are very large then you need a SAX parser.

Comment: Platform is Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use any C++ tokenizer to split input/source data in order to process each line separately (use `\r\n` as separators). 
For example you can use `boost::split` to do that. After that for each line use the same technique to extract the key and the value (use `=` as separator character). You can put parsed keys and values to a `std::map` because you'll need them on next step. The last step - simply format your target xml string using parsed data. To do that you need to *iterate through map elements* and format the result string. You can also use XML template string with *placeholders* for each attribute and replace them with parsed values.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that it would not be good approach to first convert the data into XML, until and unless its very important or there is no other choice. The reason for this is that when you are formatting the values in XML, you are increasing the number of bytes to be send over the network. Instead of this, a better approach would be send the values to the other end and convert it to XML before handing over to the C#. You can use structure approach for sending and receiving.

Comment: Actually the thing is, if the data has not formatted into xml server won't get the clue what is the data for.

Comment: You can define the message types. For example when if we are talking about hospital scenario and we are sending an image over the network, we will send a type identifier telling us whether its a patient's picture, prescription snapshot or a lab result